# table-cell manipulation using ng-if

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have to change the color of the table-cell depending on the value being entered into the cell. Basically, I want to change the style of the cell using ng-if. How can I go about it?

Comment: post some code what you have tried

Comment: Post some code. And instead of ng-if you need to use ng-class in which you vheck for condition and add class.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B6FsZjtuQmduAGCbB3pi)

HTML:

Use ng-class  `ng-class="{old : p.Age>50}"`

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-class="{old : p.Age>50}" ng-repeat="p in list">
          <td>{{p.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{p.Age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
.old{
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

**In the plunker ng-class is used on table row  , you may use use it only on cells too